# QueueUserAPC fails with INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Tags: c++, winapi, loadlibrary, dll-injection

I'm trying to inject dll into explorer.exe (simple 64bit dll that shows messagebox )

But QueueUserApc returns zero(which means error) and when I do GetLastError, it returns 6

I think something goes wrong at line 81 which calls QueueUserApc

Please help me
I'm trying to solve this problem for 2 days
 ‍  ‍  ‍  ‍  ‍  ‍

````cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

BOOL EnableDebugPriv() {
    HANDLE hToken;
    LUID Value;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
        return(GetLastError());
    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &Value))
        return(GetLastError());
    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = Value;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, NULL)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    return TRUE;
}


DWORD getPidByName(LPCSTR name, vector<DWORD> &tids) {
    DWORD pid = NULL;
    HANDLE hSnapshot = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
    THREADENTRY32 te;

    pe.dwSize = sizeof(pe);
    te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
    hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);

    Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe);
    do {
        if (strcmp(name, pe.szExeFile) == 0) {
            pid = pe.th32ProcessID;
            if (Thread32First(hSnapshot, &te)) {
                do {
                    if (te.th32OwnerProcessID == pid) {
                        tids.push_back(te.th32ThreadID);
                    } 
                } while (Thread32Next(hSnapshot, &te));
            }
            break;
        }

    } while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe));
    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);

    return pid;

}

BOOL injectDll(LPCSTR path, DWORD pid, vector<DWORD> &tids) {

    HANDLE hProcess, hThread = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    LPVOID pRemoteBuf;
    DWORD dwBufSize = lstrlen(path) + 1;
    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pThreadProc;
    if (!(hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, FALSE, pid))) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (!(pRemoteBuf = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, dwBufSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE))) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pRemoteBuf, (LPVOID)path, dwBufSize, NULL);
    pThreadProc = (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

    if (pThreadProc == NULL) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    printf("tids size: %d\n", tids.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < tids.size(); i++) {
        hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_SET_CONTEXT, FALSE, tids[i]);
        if (hThread != NULL) {
            DWORD result = QueueUserAPC((PAPCFUNC)pThreadProc, hThread, (ULONG_PTR)pRemoteBuf);
            if (result != 0) {
                printf("[*] Injection Succeed!");
            }
            else if (result == 0) {
                printf("0 RESULT\n");
                printf("result val: %d\n", result);
                printf("GetLastError: %d\n", GetLastError());
            }
            else if(hThread != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                printf("INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE");
            }
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return TRUE;
}

int main() {

    vector<DWORD> tids;
    EnableDebugPriv();
    printf("%d", getPidByName("explorer.exe", tids));
    if (injectDll("C:\\Dll1.dll", getPidByName("explorer.exe", tids), tids)) {
        printf("[*] Finally Succeed!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("ERROR");
    }
}
```c++
````

Comment: You should save the value of `GetLastError()` immediately after the function fails. Calling other OS functions (which `printf` does) can alter its value.

Comment: `QueueUserAPC` is wrong for IPC apc (because use current active activation context which is wrong for another process). you need use `ZwQueueApcThread` or `RtlQueueApcWow64Thread` if inject from 64 to 32 bit process. also you have big problem with logic - `if(hThread != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` never executed - because always will be `(result != 0)` or `(result == 0)`. `hThread` who will be close ?

Comment: use [`ZwQueueApcThread`](https://github.com/Aekras1a/Updated-Carbanak-Source-with-Plugins/blob/d40434bfa3933b5980babfb1f5552659d73e7b9d/Carbanak%20-%20part%201/botep/core/include/core/ntdll.h) or `RtlQueueApcWow64Thread` add the ntdll.h and ntdll.lib.

Answer (score 0):

> But QueueUserApc returns zero(which means error) and when I do GetLastError, it returns

"If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero."

6 = ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-queueuserapc):

> To ensure successful execution of functions used by the APC, APCs should be queued only to threads in the caller's process.

For this reason you should use ZwQueueUserAPC or ZwQueueApcThreadEx which are undocumented functions exported by ntdll.dll